# Sqoop HBase Import: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor.addFamily

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop, hbase, sqoop

I'm running Hadoop as a pseudo distributed cluster on Ubuntu 14.04. I've installed HBase as well and everything works fine. Now I want to import data from my local MySql Server to HBase using the "import" command from Sqoop

- Hadoop Version: 2.7.3
- HBase Version: 1.2.4
- Sqoop Version: 1.4.6 (Hadoop 2.0.4-alpha)

Hadoop and HBase are working fine without problems, but running the command

```
./sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/company --table people --username mysqluser -P --hbase-table people_import --column-family peoplecf --hbase-create-table
```

results in the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor.addFamily(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/HColumnDescriptor;)V
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.HBaseImportJob.jobSetup(HBaseImportJob.java:222)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:264)
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:673)
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.importTable(MySQLManager.java:118)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:497)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop does not support the latest versions of Hbase yet.
The latest of Sqoop is compatible with versions of Hbase <= 0.95.2, there is an open [issue (SQOOP-2759)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-2759) for this hbase-sqoop integration.